# Swift - GoogleMaps SDK get single or double finger tap gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift4

I am using Google Maps SDK in my project. I want to check and detect when tap on google map that is used single finger or double finger ?
My requirement is, disable single finger use and enable double finger use. I want all Gestures work on double finger not on single finger.

Answer (score 3):

First, disable all gesture on your `GMSMapView` instance. Documentation says:

`You can disable the default gestures on the map by setting properties of the GMSUISettings class, which is available as a property of the GMSMapView`

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/controls

Then you may be able to add some UITapGestureRecognizer:

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer

Don't forget to set `numberOfTouchesRequired` to `2` !

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer/1623580-numberoftouchesrequired

Comment: Let me check this :)